# Compatibility of code Progress 8 to OpenEdge 11

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

we have an ERP system running in our company based on Progress 8. Can you give an indication how compatible OpenEdge 11 is to version 8? Is it like "compile the source" and it will run (of course testing :-)) or more like every second line will need rework?

I know it's a general question but maybe you can provide a general answer? :o)

Thanks,
Gunter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Convert the db and recompile.

Sometimes you might run across keyword conflicts.  A quick fix for that is the -k parameter (the "keyword forget list").  Using -k is a quick way to get old code that has variables or table/field names  that have become new keywords to compile while you work on changing the names.

You might also see the occasional situation where the compiler has tightened up the rules a bit.  For instance, there was some tightening of rules around defining shared variables in the v8/v9 time frame -- most of what I remember about that was looking at the impacted code and asking myself "how did that *ever* compile to start with?"

Another potential issue -- if your application uses a framework (such as "smart objects") whose API might change from release to release it is important to make sure that you compile against the version of that framework that your code requires -- not something newer but different.

Obviously you need to test but the overwhelmingly vast majority of code recompiles and runs without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We just did the conversion from Progress 8.3E to OpenEdge 11 a few days ago. It went on much like Tom wrote. Convert and recompile.

The only problem was one database that was originally created in Progress version 7 . Here conversion failed - but since it was a small database, it was quicker to dump , recreate and load.